# use of deleted function ‘sf::RenderWindow& sf::RenderWindow::operator=(const sf::RenderWindow&)’

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm pretty new to C++ so please go easy on me.

I'm trying to use sfml to create a RenderWindow. Then, on creation of a player, that player's associated "window" object gets set to the RenderWindow created previously. My purpose is to be able to run window methods, such as window.draw(), from the player object, i.e.:

```
player::drawSprite() {
    window.draw(sprite);
}
```

However, I run into the error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘sf::RenderWindow& sf::RenderWindow::operator=(const sf::RenderWindow&)’
         window = win;
                ^
```

Further down in the error log, I also see:

```
error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘Player::Player(sf::RenderWindow)’
     Player(sf::RenderWindow win)
     ^
```

My code (with anything not pertinent to the question omitted) is as follows:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

class Player
{
private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float speed;
    sf::RenderWindow window;
public:
    Player(sf::RenderWindow win)
    {
        x = 640;
        y = 360;
        speed = 5;
        window = win;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //Window Initialization
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My window");

    //Player Creation
    Player player(window);
}
```

I believe the problem may have something to do with const's, references, or the like, but I am not familiar enough with C++ to easily identify it. How can I remedy this issue?

Comment: I don't know SFML, but it looks like `sf::RenderWindow` is non-copyable and has it's assignment operator deleted.  You possibly need to change the declaration for `Player::Player` to take a reference (or pointer) to `sf::RenderWindow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use reference or pointer to window object as I don't think that you will want each player to have its own window.

Thus your Player should look like:

```
class Player
{
private:
    float x;
    float y;
    float speed;
    sf::RenderWindow& window;     // reference
public:
    Player(sf::RenderWindow& win) // accepts reference
      : window(win)               // stores reference     
    {
        x = 640;
        y = 360;
        speed = 5;
        // window = win;
    }
};
```

Comment: Remove `window = win;`