# error: ‘sf::NonCopyable& sf::NonCopyable::operator=(const sf::NonCopyable&)’ is private within this context

Tags: c++, constructor, sfml

### About problem

My problem is quite popular and I found a solution to it. However, I can't understand why when I assign a window in the constructor an error pops up, but when I assign a window in the initialization list everything works.

### Good code

```
class Player : public sf::CircleShape
{
private:
   int X;
   int Y;
   sf::Image image;
   sf::Texture texture;
   sf::Sprite sprite;
   sf::RectangleShape rectangle;
   sf::RenderWindow& window;
public:
   Player(sf::RenderWindow& win, sf::Image image) : window(win){}
};
```

### Error code

```
class Player : public sf::CircleShape
{
private:
   int X;
   int Y;
   sf::Image image;
   sf::Texture texture;
   sf::Sprite sprite;
   sf::RectangleShape rectangle;
   sf::RenderWindow& window;
public:
   Player(sf::RenderWindow& win, sf::Image image) 
   {
     window = win;
   }
};
```

### Links

Below is a link to the answer I found. Maybe it will help you in solving my problem. I found there the answer to my question , but I still do not understand why I can not assign a window in the constructor.

[use of deleted function ‘sf::RenderWindow& sf::RenderWindow::operator=(const sf::RenderWindow&)’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444949/use-of-deleted-function-sfrenderwindow-sfrenderwindowoperator-const-sf)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can't assign references. Instead of `window = win;`  use `Player(sf::RenderWindow& win, sf::Image image) : window{win} {}`

Comment: Initializing via the initializer list and assigning in the body of the constructor are 2 different things: Before the body of the constructor is entered, the initialization for every single non-static member variable runs, so anything you put inside the body works with already constructed objects (assuming the type of the variable is a class). There should be another compiler error complaining about the reference not being initialized...

Answer (score 3):

I'll use a simplified version.

##### Good

```cpp
int main() {
    int a = 0, b = 123;

    int& x = a;
    x = b;       // assigns 123 to a, a is now 123
}
```

##### Bad

```cpp
int main() {
    int a = 0, b = 123;

    int& x;      // <- error here
    x = b;       // would assign 123 to the variable x should be referencing
}
```

Why is the *Bad* version bad?

- References *must* be initialized. Once initialized, they can't (legally) be made to reference another object.

Why?

- Because of language rules. If you want something that may be set to *not* reference another object, you have pointers. Initialize a pointer with `nullptr` and make it point at an object at a later time. However, something that *can* be `nullptr` also needs to be checked by functions if they have no other way of knowing that it's not `nullptr`. You don't need to check if a reference is referencing anything. It is. Had your *Bad* version been legal, that promise would not hold.

Also think about what it would mean to references if `x = b;` made `x` reference `b` instead of what it actually does: Assigning the value that `b` holds to the object `x` is referencing.